# Math operations with matrices inside differents objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

In javascript, I have the following object:

```
console.log(data)

(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {species: "Citronela paniculata", cbh: Array(1)}
1: {species: "Myrcia splendens", cbh: Array(1)}
2: {species: "Araucaria angustifolia", plot: 1, cbh: Array(1)}
3: {species: "Bacharis montana", cbh: Array(1)}
4:
cbh: (2) [10, 20]
plot: 1
species: "Casearia decandra"
__proto__: Object
5: {cbh: Array(1), species: "Bacharis montana"}
6: {cbh: Array(3), species: "Ilex paraguariensis"}
7: {cbh: Array(1), species: "Ilex paraguariensis"}
8: {species: "Ilex paraguariensis", cbh: Array(1)}
9: {plot: 1, cbh: Array(1), species: "Araucaria angustifolia"}
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I would like to divide each element of the array cbh by pi, then I used:

```
let newData = data.map(({ plot, species, cbh }) => {

        let dbh = cbh/Math.PI;

        return { plot, species, cbh, dbh };


    })
```

But for those array with more than one elements I got NaN:

```
 console.log(newData)

(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {plot: undefined, species: "Citronela paniculata", cbh: Array(1), dbh: 9.549296585513721}
1: {plot: undefined, species: "Myrcia splendens", cbh: Array(1), dbh: 10.185916357881302}
2: {plot: 1, species: "Araucaria angustifolia", cbh: Array(1), dbh: 5.729577951308232}
3: {plot: undefined, species: "Bacharis montana", cbh: Array(1), dbh: 4.7746482927568605}
4:
cbh: (2) [10, 20]
dbh: NaN
plot: 1
species: "Casearia decandra"
__proto__: Object
5: {plot: undefined, species: "Bacharis montana", cbh: Array(1), dbh: 6.366197723675814}
6: {plot: undefined, species: "Ilex paraguariensis", cbh: Array(3), dbh: NaN}
7: {plot: undefined, species: "Ilex paraguariensis", cbh: Array(1), dbh: 6.366197723675814}
8: {plot: undefined, species: "Ilex paraguariensis", cbh: Array(1), dbh: 15.915494309189533}
9: {plot: 1, species: "Araucaria angustifolia", cbh: Array(1), dbh: 15.915494309189533}
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
```

How to get each element in cbh divided by pi? Any tips would be awesome! Thank you in advance!

Comment: You'll have to iterate through the array and divide each element separately. You can do that with the `.map()` function on the Array prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dividing an array with one element by `Math.PI`, the result is a number. One-element array is implicitly converted to a number, but an array with a large number of elements cannot be converted to a number, so NaN is obtained.  In any case, this method of division will not work, because the output will not return an array, but a number or NaN.

To achieve the target result, you can use [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which converts source array to new array, applying a
specified transformation to each element of source array (in this case, division by `Math.PI`):

```
let newData = data.map(({ plot, species, cbh }) => {
    const dbh = cbh.map(value => value / Math.PI);

    return { plot, species, cbh, dbh };
})
```